# turnings rows in dataframe into columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a CSV which i read into a python dataframe and it looks like this:

df =

```
0|country, city, currency|
1|"England", "London", "GBP"|
2|"Spain", "Madrid", "EUR"|
3|"America", "Washington", "USD"|
4|"Japan", "Tokyo", "JPY"|
```

Right now there is only one column and many rows, the first row contains all the names of the columns i need. I want to split everything by the commas and put into individual columns so it would look like this:

df =

```
 |country    city       currency
0|England    London     GBP
1|Spain      Madrid     EUR
2|America    Washington USD
3|Japan      Tokyo      JPY
```

Comment: is ```|``` part of the data as well? because it seems, you could read the data in with ```sep=',' ``` or set ```sep=None```, to allow python automatically detect the delimiter

Answer (score 0):

Cannot comment to ask for clarification, but what about the `sep` parameter of `pandars.read_csv` ([documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html))? It defaults to `,`, so should properly read your CSV (maybe provide that in your question as well?).

This answer assumes that the question is a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), since the problem is to read the CSV properly instead of trying to fix the resulting dataframe after the fact.